# ConfigureAutomapper to map contents of collection-property, but use destination collection object

Tags: c#, automapper

I have a class

```
class A
{
  public A()
  {
    CollectionProp = new List<B>();
  }
  public ICollection<B> CollectionProp {get; private set;}
}
```

Lets say that I want to map from A -> A, as a cloning mechanism, but I dont want AutoMapper to attempt to create the CollectionProp, it should just use the CollectionProp that exists in the destination object (created by the constructor), but clone all the 'B' objects from A into the new instance of A.

How do I do this.. So far I have:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<A, A>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.CollectionProp, opt => opt.MapFrom(e => e.CollectionProp));
```

Which appears to use the CollectionProp from the newly created object, but its not filling up its elements.

What am I missing?

Thanks

Comment: `class` belongs in front of the first `A`, not the second.

Comment: haha... woops. updating.

Comment: The more research I do, the more it seems that AutoMapper doesnt support using the target object's Collection (property), but populating it with mapped instances from the source...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one worked for me

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<A, A>()
            .ConvertUsing((s) => {
                var d = new A(); 
                d.CollectionProp.AddRange(s.CollectionProp); 
                return d;
            });
```

Ok. This one actually clones the Bs

```
            Mapper.CreateMap<B,B>();

            Mapper.CreateMap<A, A>()
            .ConvertUsing(s => {
                var d = new A();
                s.CollectionProp.ToList()
                    .ForEach(b => d.CollectionProp.Add(Mapper.Map<B,B>(b)));
                return d;
            });
```

Comment: Doesnt that add all the elements from the original object, to the new collection?
I need the elements to be 'cloned' aswell. Nothing in my my new objectmodel should be shared with the original.

Comment: I also wouldnt have thought that syntax was valid... "d => d", you're not specifying a property.

Comment: I changed the answer to clone the Bs

Comment: Ah, so it seems that Automapper doesnt support this scenario, but it gives you enough control to achieve it - I think I would probably go with ICloneable instead as there doesnt appear much advantage in using AutoMapper.
Thanks